# Does CUDA automatically load-balance for you?

Tags: cuda, load-balancing, gpgpu

I'm hoping for some general advice and clarification on best practices for load balancing in CUDA C, in particular:

- If 1 thread in a warp takes longer than the other 31, will it hold up the other 31 from completing?
- If so, will the spare processing capacity be assigned to another warp?
- Why do we need the notion of warp *and* block? Seems to me a warp is just a small block of 32 threads.
- So in general, for a given call to a kernel what do I need load balance?

  - Threads in each warp?
  - Threads in each block?
  - Threads across all blocks?

Finally, to give an example, what load balancing techniques you would use for the following function:

1. I have a vector `x0` of `N` points: `[1, 2, 3, ..., N]`
2. I randomly select 5% of the points and `log` them (or some complicated function)
3. I write the resulting vector `x1` (e.g. `[1, log(2), 3, 4, 5, ..., N]`) to memory
4. I repeat the above 2 operations on `x1` to yield `x2` (e.g. `[1, log(log(2)), 3, 4, log(5), ..., N]`), and then do a further 8 iterations to yield `x3` ... `x10`
5. I return `x10`

Many thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Threads are grouped into three levels that are scheduled differently.  Warps utilize SIMD for higher compute density.  Thread blocks utilize multithreading for latency tolerance.  Grids provide independent, coarse-grained units of work for load balancing across SMs.

## Threads in a warp

The hardware executes the 32 threads of a warp together.  It can execute 32 instances of a single instruction with different data.  If the threads take different control flow, so they are not all executing the same instruction, then some of those 32 execution resources will be idle while the instruction executes.  This is called *control divergence* in CUDA references.

If a kernel exhibits a lot of control divergence, it may be worth redistributing work at this level.  This balances work by keeping all execution resources busy within a warp.  You can reassign work between threads as shown below.

```
// Identify which data should be processed
if (should_do_work(threadIdx.x)) {
  int tmp_index = atomicAdd(&tmp_counter, 1); 
  tmp[tmp_index] = threadIdx.x;
}
__syncthreads();

// Assign that work to the first threads in the block
if (threadIdx.x < tmp_counter) {
  int thread_index = tmp[threadIdx.x];
  do_work(thread_index); // Thread threadIdx.x does work on behalf of thread tmp[threadIdx.x]
}
```

## Warps in a block

On an SM, the hardware schedules warps onto execution units.  Some instructions take a while to complete, so the scheduler interleaves the execution of multiple warps to keep the execution units busy.  If some warps are not ready to execute, they are skipped with no performance penalty.

There is usually no need for load balancing at this level.  Simply ensure that enough warps are available per thread block so that the scheduler can always find a warp that is ready to execute.

## Blocks in a grid

The runtime system schedules blocks onto SMs.  Several blocks can run concurrently on an SM.

There is usually no need for load balancing at this level.  Simply ensure that enough thread blocks are available to fill all SMs several times over.  It is useful to overprovision thread blocks to minimize the load imbalance at the end of a kernel, when some SMs are idle and no more thread blocks are ready to execute.

Comment: What precisely do you mean when a warp is "_ready to execute_"? Surely all warps waiting to be executed are "_ready_" to be executed. Thanks.

Comment: Also, what do you mean when a warp is "_skipped with no penalty_"? If I've got a warp I want to execute, it's no good to me skipping it! And what "_penalty_" are we talking about here? Thanks.

Comment: On another note, do warps from the same block run _concurrently_ on an SM? If so, then if one warp exhibits control divergence, will another concurrently executing warp (on the same SM) make use of the spare processing capacity?

Comment: Similarly, you mention "_several blocks can run concurrently on an SM_". So if one block exhibits control divergence, will the other concurrently executing block (on the same SM) make use of the spare processing capacity?

Comment: @Milo A warp may be unable to execute, or stalled, because a previous instruction has not finished.  For example, in the statement `x = 1 + p[threadIdx.x];`, the GPU's hardware scheduler will not attempt to execute the `+` operation until after the array read has finished.  It will execute other warps in the meantime.  As long as other warps can be executed, the unready `+` operation does not incur any overhead.

Comment: @Milo All NVIDIA GPUs have some degree of concurrency.  Still, the hardware scheduler operates at the granularity of one instruction×warp.  If fewer than 32 threads in a warp execute a particular instruction, then some execution resources will be unused for the duration of that instruction.  The hardware will not reassign them to do other work.

Answer (score 5):

As others have already said, the threads within a warp use a scheme called Single Instruction, Multiple Data (SIMD.) SIMD means that there is a single instruction decoding unit in the hardware controling multiple arithmetic and logic units (ALU's.) A CUDA 'core' is basically just a floating-point ALU, not a full core in the same sense as a CPU core. While the exact CUDA core to instruction decoder ratio varies between different CUDA Compute Capability versions, all of them use this scheme. Since they all use the same instruction decoder, each thread within a warp of threads will execute the exact same instruction on every clock cycle. The cores assigned to the threads within that warp that do not follow the currently-executing code path will simply do nothing on that clock cycle. There is no way to avoid this, as it is an intentional physical hardware limitation. Thus, if you have 32 threads in a warp and each of those 32 threads follows a different code path, you will have no speedup from parallelism at all within that warp. It will execute each of those 32 code paths sequentially. This is why it is ideal for all threads within the warp to follow the same code path as much as possible, since parallelism within a warp is only possible when multiple threads are following the same code path.

The reason that the hardware is designed this way is that it saves chip space. Since each core doesn't have its own instruction decoder, the cores themselves take up less chip space (and use less power.) Having smaller cores that use less power per core means that more cores can be packed onto the chip. Having small cores like this is what allows GPU's to have hundreds or thousands of cores per chip while CPU's only have 4 or 8, even while maintaining similar chip sizes and power consumption (and heat dissipation) levels. The trade off with SIMD is that you can pack a lot more ALU's onto the chip and get a lot more parallelism, but you only get the speedup when those ALU's are all executing the same code path. The reason this trade off is made to such a high degree for GPU's is that much of the computation involved in 3D graphics processing is simply floating-point matrix multiplication. SIMD lends itself well to matrix multiplication because the process to compute each output value of the resultant matrix is identical, just on different data. Furthermore, each output value can be computed completely independently of every other output value, so the threads don't need to communicate with each other at all. Incidentally, similar patterns (and often even matrix multiplication itself) also happen to appear commonly in scientific and engineering applications. This is why General Purpose processing on GPU's (GPGPU) was born. CUDA (and GPGPU in general) was basically an afterthought on how existing hardware designs which were already being mass produced for the gaming industry could also be used to speed up other types of parallel floating-point processing applications.

Answer (score 4):

> If 1 thread in a warp takes longer than the other 31, will it hold up the other 31 from completing?

Yes. As soon as you have divergence in a Warp, the scheduler needs to take all divergent branches and process them one by one. The compute capacity of the threads not in the currently executed branch will then be lost. You can check the CUDA Programming Guide, it explains quite well what exactly happens.

> If so, will the spare processing capacity be assigned to another warp?

No, unfortunately that is completely lost.

> Why do we need the notion of warp and block? Seems to me a warp is just a small block of 32 threads.

Because a Warp has to be SIMD (single instruction, multiple data) to achieve optimal performance, the Warps inside a block can be completely divergent, however, they share some other resources. (Shared Memory, Registers, etc.)

> So in general, for a given call to a kernel what do I need load balance?

I don't think load balance is the right word here. Just make sure, that you always have enough Threads being executed all the time and avoid divergence inside warps. Again, the CUDA Programming Guide is a good read for things like that.

Now for the example:

You could execute m threads with m=0..N*0.05, each picking a random number and putting the result of the "complicated function" in x1[m].
However, randomly reading from global memory over a large area isn't the most efficient thing you can do with a GPU, so you should also think about whether that really needs to be completely random.

Answer (score 2):

Others have provided good answers for the theoretical questions.

For your example, you might consider restructuring the problem as follows:

1. have a vector `x` of `N` points: `[1, 2, 3, ..., N]`
2. compute some complicated function on every element of `x`, yielding `y`.
3. randomly sample subsets of `y` to produce `y0` through `y10`.

Step 2 operates on every input element exactly once, without consideration for whether that value is needed.  If step 3's sampling is done without replacement, this means that you'll be computing 2x the number of elements you'll actually need, but you'll be computing everything with no control divergence and all memory access will be coherent.  These are often much more important drivers of speed on GPUs than the computation itself, but this depends on what the complicated function is really doing.

Step 3 will have a non-coherent memory access pattern, so you'll have to decide whether it's better to do it on the GPU or whether it's faster to transfer it back to the CPU and do the sampling there.

Depending on what the next computation is, you might restructure step 3 to instead randomly draw an integer in [0,N) for each element.  If the value is in [N/2,N) then ignore it in the next computation.  If it's in [0,N/2), then associate its value with an accumulator for that virtual `y*` array (or whatever is appropriate for your computation).

Answer (score 1):

Your example is a really good way of showing of reduction.

```
I have a vector x0 of N points: [1, 2, 3, ..., N]
I randomly pick 50% of the points and log them (or some complicated function) (1)
I write the resulting vector x1 to memory (2)
I repeat the above 2 operations on x1 to yield x2, and then do a further 8 iterations to  yield x3 ... x10 (3)
I return x10 (4)
```

Say |x0| = 1024, and you pick 50% of the points.

The first stage could be the only stage where you have to read from the global memory, I will show you why.

512 threads read 512 values from memory(1), it stores them into shared memory (2), then for step (3) 256 threads will read random values from shared memory and store them also in shared memory. You do this until you end up with one thread, which will write it back to global memory (4).

You could extend this further by at the initial step having 256 threads reading two values, or 128 threads reading 4 values, etc...

Comment: Thanks, I think you misunderstand and I should clarify. When I say I "_pick_" 5% of the points I simply mean "_choose_", rather than "_extract to form a new vector_".

Thus for example, `x1 = [1, log(2), 3, 4, log(5), 6, ...]` and `x2 = [1, log(log(2)), 3, 4, log(5), log(6), ...]`. I've now amended the wording in the main question to avoid further confusion.